# The first uncountable ordinal and some stationary sets

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, large-cardinals

We define a subset $A$ of an ordinal $\alpha$ as stationary iff we have $A$ intersecting every closed and unbounded subset of $\alpha$. Equivalently, one can define this as

$$\forall f:\alpha\mapsto\alpha,\exists\beta\in A,\forall\gamma\in\beta(f(\gamma)\in\beta)$$

I'm curious about $\omega_1$, and whether or not the following is satisfied:

> For every set $A$ of stationary subsets of $\omega_1$, define $B$ as the set of ordinals $\beta$ such that $\beta\cap A_\star$ is stationary in $\beta$ for all $A_\star\in A$. Whenever $B$ is uncountable, is $B$ a stationary subset of $\omega_1$?

By having $\min A_\star$ be unbounded, we can make $B$ empty, and by similar arguments we can make it contain countably many ordinals. However, I'm not sure if we can make $B$ uncountable without trivially being stationary.

It may also be helpful to note that in order for $\beta\cap A_\star$ to be stationary in countable $\beta$, we must have $\sup(\beta\setminus A_\star)\in\beta$.

---

My curiosity on whether or not the above is true or not stems from trying to see if the above is equivalent to a large cardinal, namely something like weakly compact cardinals. Hence why my intuition says the above is false.

Comment: If there is a non-reflecting stationary set (I seem to recall this is the case in $L$, for example), then you can find a singleton $A$ such that $B$ is empty.

Comment: Also, how do you define stationary reflection on $\omega_1$? All the points below it are of countable cofinality...

Comment: What do you mean by stationary reflection? I believe I have provided all of the definitions directly involved here.

Comment: (1) a stationary set $S$ reflects at $\beta$ if $S\cap\beta$ is stationary at $\beta$. (2) If $\beta$ has countable cofinality, fix a cofinal sequence $\{\beta_n\mid n<\omega\}$, then it is closed and unbounded, therefore a stationary set must be a tail segment since it meets all unbounded sequences of order type $\omega$. This is why stationarity is almost entirely discussed in the context of uncountable cofinalities.

Comment: Yes, I have pointed that out in the edit. Even so I am interested in this case.

Comment: By all means though, I am interested in the case of this for larger ordinals than $\omega_1$, as pointed out by the end, if you wish to comment on that as well.

Comment: Hm, so since countable cofinality ruins this, do you have any idea what happens when we consider ordinals $\beta\in\kappa$ such that $\beta$ has uncountable cofinality, for $\kappa>\omega_1$?

Answer (score 1):

The set of countable ordinals which aren't successors of limit ordinals forms a stationary set, since it contains every countable limit ordinal. This reflects at every countable limit ordinal which isn't a limit of limit ordinals. However, the set of limits of limit ordinals is club, so this set isn't stationary. In general, replacing $\omega_1$ with any ordinal fails to have this property by the same construction as above.